# Animated plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, plot

I am trying to create an animated plot of triangles and the end result should be ten triangles followed by two bigger triangles followed by a straight line. Using the [matlab documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html), I ended up having this, which results an animated sin plot:

```
h = animatedline;
axis([0 4*pi -1 1])
x = linspace(0,4*pi,2000);

for k = 1:length(x)
    y = sin(x(k));
    addpoints(h,x(k),y);
    drawnow
end
```

The problem is that the plot is really slow and as soon as I changed `y=sin(x(k))` to a triangular form, it got even worst. Is there a better way to do an animated plot or at least to adjust the speed? (if the speed is not dependant on the computer)

Answer (score 1):

You can speed it up a little by

- Computing a `y` vector at once, instead of computing each value in the loop.
- Updating the `XData` and `YData` properties of a `plot`, instead of using `animatedline`.

The code becomes:

```
h = plot(NaN,NaN);
axis([0 4*pi -1 1])
x = linspace(0,4*pi,2000);
y = sin(x);

for k = 1:length(x)
    set(h, 'XData', x(1:k), 'YData', y(1:k))
    drawnow
end
```

The gain in speed is small, though. If you need more speed you probably need to decrease the number of points.

Answer (score 0):

You can examine `comet` function to animate the curve:

```
t = linspace(0,4*pi,2000);
comet(t, sin(t));
```

It would be smooth and easier to animate a curve (see its [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/comet.html)).
Also, for 3d curves you can use `comet3`.