# Why does video code in MATLAB run slowly?

Tags: performance, matlab, video

I am running a MATLAB code which produces a discrete element simulation at the end of the code. The code produces a simulation of particle locations as shown in the figure below. Currently, the code to produce this simulation is running incredibly slow. The simulation is slow to the point that's it's not practical to watch it. I put the movie part of the code below, does anyone have ideas to speed this part of the code up? Also, does anyone know how to control the pace at which MATLAB plots the circles and lines in the code?

Thanks

[image]

```
%% Movie Output

if SkipMovie == 1
    
    Start = 1;
    INTMOVIE = 1;
    End = NT;
    
    for TimeStep = Start:INTMOVIE:End % For 1 to the number of time steps at interval INTMOVIE
        dim = [0.15,.95,.25,.06];     % Location of Time Step Text Box
        str = {sprintf(sprintf('TimeStep = %3.2f',TimeStep))};   % Text in Time Step Text Box
        annotation('textbox', dim, 'String', str,'BackgroundColor','w'); % Draw text box
        for j = 1:NP % for 1 to the number of particles 
            
            th = 0:pi/50:2*pi;
            x_circle = R(j) * cos(th) + LPart(j,1,TimeStep); %LPart gives the x/y postition of particle j at the corresponding time step
            y_circle = R(j) * sin(th) + LPart(j,2,TimeStep);
            plot(x_circle, y_circle); % Draw a circle for particle j
            fill(x_circle, y_circle, colorP) % Fill circle for particle j
            
            hold on;
            GW1 = plot(LWall(1,1:2),LWall(1,3:4),['-',colorW]); % Draw Wall 1
            GW2 = plot(LWall(2,1:2),LWall(2,3:4),['-',colorW]); % Draw Wall 2
            GW3 = plot(LWall(3,1:2),LWall(3,3:4),['-',colorW]); % Draw Wall 3
            GW4 = plot(LWall(4,1:2),LWall(4,3:4),['-',colorW]); % Draw Wall 4
            GW5 = plot(LWall(5,1:2),LWall(5,3:4),['-',colorW]); % Draw Wall 5
            GW6 = plot(LWall(6,1:2),LWall(6,3:4),['-',colorW]); % Draw Wall 6
            
            set(GW1(1),'LineWidth',2); % Set Line Width of Wall 1
            set(GW2(1),'LineWidth',2); % Set Line Width of Wall 2
            set(GW3(1),'LineWidth',2); % Set Line Width of Wall 3
            set(GW4(1),'LineWidth',2); % Set Line Width of Wall 4
            set(GW5(1),'LineWidth',2); % Set Line Width of Wall 5
            set(GW6(1),'LineWidth',2); % Set Line Width of Wall 6
            axis([xdim1,xdim2,ydim1,ydim2]); % Set viewing window of plot
        end
        FF = getframe; % Save the plotted frame to FF
        hold off; % Hold current frame until items for next frame are drawn (not sure if this is needed)
        clf; % clear frame before loops repeat
    end
    movie(FF,repeat,1) % Create movie based on frame FF
end
```

Comment: This code woul dnot show an animation. In the loop, you overwrite FF each time, so after the `Timestep` loop, there is only 1 frame for the movie to play. On top of that, you seem to be creating some things `NP` times without clearing them up, as all the GWX are re-plotted in the loop, which will make everything unnecesarily slower. You may want to explain what are you doing in each section, because to me this code just looks bad in general, and I am not sure how it can plot a movie.

Comment: The code is supposed to create a movie frame by frame from the resulting simulation. I am not well versed in video outputs in MATLAB, so this is the only way I know how to make a video (by plotting it frame by frame and updating the frame for each new time step). I put some more notes in the code so hopefully it's easier to read.

Comment: I will not close as duplicate, because there are more issues here than just this, but to start you should read here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45263552/7328782

Comment: Also, to draw a filled circle, use the `rectangle` function (sounds counter-intuitive, but look at the docs). Being a single object, it'll be much easier to update its properties to animate it.

Comment: Please do then try to understand the code you posted. Do you see why you are repeating the GW plots unnecesarily? Do you see how you only grab the frame once, then overwrite it before the `movie`?